# Moving a .doc with a sting of 46 and 45 digits to a path folder in Powershell

Tags: powershell

Hope someone can help.  I have a script I wrote in Autohotkey, which I want to move .doc files 46 characters in length to a folder and move files 45 characters to a separate folder. The code works but has issues. I want to run this in powershell. Thanks in advance.

See my code below:

```
Loop, D:\IHC\CoderConvertUploadCerner\step1\2*.doc,
{stringlen, length, A_LoopFileName
ifless, length, 46
{
filemove, %A_LoopFileFullPath%,        
D:\IHC\CoderConvertUploadCerner\step1\Step1.5Core\%A_LoopFileName%
}
else ifgreaterorequal, length, 46
{
filemove, %A_LoopFileFullPath%, 
D:\IHC\CoderConvertUploadCerner\step1\Step1.5Cerner\%A_LoopFileName%
}
if errorlevel
    break
}

Loop, D:\IHC\CoderConvertUploadCerner\step1\2*.doc,
{stringlen, length, A_LoopFileName
ifless, length, 46
{
filemove, %A_LoopFileFullPath%,   
D:\IHC\CoderConvertUploadCerner\step1\Step1.5Core\%A_LoopFileName%
}
else ifgreaterorequal, length, 45
{
filemove, %A_LoopFileFullPath%,   
D:\IHC\CoderConvertUploadCerner\step1\Step1.5Cerner\%A_LoopFileName%
}
if errorlevel
    break
}
```

Comment: Maybe you can elaborate a bit on what the issues are? Best wishes.

Answer (score 0):

A straight conversion of your first code block is this:

```
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop';
Get-ChildItem 'D:\IHC\CoderConvertUploadCerner\step1\2*.doc' |
ForEach-Object 
{
    if ($_.Name.Length -lt 46) 
    {
        Move-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination "D:\IHC\CoderConvertUploadCerner\step1\Step1.5Core\$($_.Name)";
    }
    elseif ($_.Name.Length -ge 46)
    {
        Move-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination "D:\IHC\CoderConvertUploadCerner\step1\Step1.5Cerner\$($_.Name)";
    }
}
```

The second code block appears to be identical, but has an apparent logic error since it uses "less than 46" followed by "greater than or equal to 45", which is an overlap.

However, since you haven't told us what's actually wrong, it's not possible to help any further.

Comment: It should read 45 instead of 46, sorry about that.. but this helps a lot sorry for the confusion.